# apache roller 5.1 link error

Tags: apache, hyperlink, blogs

my apache roller 5.1 installation has some links that work, and some that don't. It's hosted on digitalocean. The 'Home' link starts out with 127.0.0.1:8080 which of course doesn't work, yet the login link is correctly formed starting with the domain name, instead.

I think this is a apache roller configuration error, but I'm not sure how to fix it. What would cause some links to start with 127.0.0.1:8080, and some to start with the sites real domain name?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details to this issue? Are these misleading links, links to resources like CSS, images, etc. or to blog posts?

In common, this sounds like a misconfiguration of your Java EE server. If your application server is listening to localhost (127.0.0.1), Apache Roller will use this IP address for the URLs.

Let the application server listen to the external IP address and the issue should be solved.